# How to convert php file into html file

Tags: php

I'm a frontend developer and I'm facing with a problem.

Whenever I'm building a website, I'm using PHP to include the template files, so I get a redundant code.
But when I want to generate this file into an HTML file I open up the PHP file in the browser to copy/paste the code to an HTML file.

How can I make this process to be way much faster, or how could I avoid to do these things manually? Maybe there is a program to do this or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive `wget`.

Say your webserver runs on your localhost, you can run:

```
wget -r -k localhost
```

**Be careful**: `wget`does not perform a search on which pages are available, it simply looks at links (the `<a>` tags) and will capture these as well. As long as everything is reachable from the index page (not necessarily on the index page), it will be downloaded.

`wget` is a linux program, but I guess there is a Windows application with the same name/options as well... As @rkbvkleef points out, it's part of the *MinGW* package.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your php file (which runs on server, could be local server) contains or generates your HTML code to present on browser. You can simply write HTML code out of  tags in a php file and it will work. Or if you want to generate some HTML based on some conditions you are checking inside php or using some variables in php then you can use echo function. It will display whatever string you echo on your webpage.

```
<?php
$name = "Murtaza";
echo("<h1>Hello ".$name."</h1>");
?>
```